# Get values from database to ListView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have written this fetchData() method to fill ListView with the values from database.

```
public void fetchData() {
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.query(db.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String[] fromDB={db.FULLNAME,db.YEAR};
    int[] toView={R.id.tvName_lv,R.id.tv_birthday_lv};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_all, c, fromDB, toView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It works fine. But when I try to use it this way, it gives an error.

```
public void fetchData() {
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.query(db.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String birthday=db.YEAR+" "+db.MONTH+" "+db.DAY;
    String[] fromDB={db.FULLNAME,birthday};
    int[] toView={R.id.tvName_lv,R.id.tv_birthday_lv};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_all, c, fromDB, toView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I want to get [db.YEAR+" "+db.MONTH+" "+db.DAY] to the view [R.id.tv_birthday_lv]
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:Error is "Unfortunately, App has stopped". FATAL EXCEPTION on LogCat

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please provide Logcat output.

Comment: Unfortunately, App has stopped. FATAL EXCEPTION on LogCat

Comment: there is no such column as String birthday points to,  you have to use a ViewBinder to concat those three columns

Comment: @pskink - can you please show me how to do it? I'm new to android and java

Comment: Use a custom adapter instead, pass the cursor as parameter. Check: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/